# Adding a servo to existing project with two motors

Tags: servo

Currently I have [this](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051) setup running. I would like to add [my old robbe servo](http://www.servodatabase.com/servo/robbe/fs-100) to this setup. There are many tutorials for a servo setup, however, I do not have enough knowledge to combine the schemas properly. I am particularly afraid of damaging my pi. Below is the schema I am using for my two motors.

[image]

Can anyone draw the wiring for the servo onto the image and explain why you have done it that way?

Further questions:

- is the above even possible with the current setup?
- is the power supply sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

A servo only has three connections, power, ground, and control.

Connect the power and ground to the breadboard just as for the DC motors.

Connect the control wire to **any** spare GPIO.

Send servo pulses using PWM to the servo GPIO.

It is impossible to say if there will be enough power.  We have no idea about the power requirements of your current set-up.